# Multivariate Bayesian Car Model Result

Tags: multivariate-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, lognormal-distribution, poisson-process, car

I have developed a multivariate Bayesian Car model for three crash severity level analysis. I found that the covariance for both heterogenous effects and the spatial effect is not significant for any severity type.

What does the result mean?

Comment: Could you please add some more details to your question? What does your model look like? How did you specify the spatial effect? What do you mean by the covariance is not significant?

Comment: I developed a Multivariate Poisson Lognormal model with spatial effect (CAR) to analyze crash of three severity levels as this paper did (Huang, H., Zhou, H., Wang, J., Chang, F., & Ma, M. (2017). A multivariate spatial model of crash frequency by transportation modes for urban intersections. Analytic methods in accident research, 14, 10-21)

Table 3 and 4 of this paper presented Variance-covariance matrix for heterogeneous and Spatial effects. I am trying to understand what does it mean if the Covariance of three crash severity level is not significant (standard deviation> than mean)?